# Case class: performances of always copying vs check for differences before copying

Tags: scala, performance, case-class

Lets say i have the following class:

```
case class Foo(words: List[String])
```

I want to make a method member of this class that removes an element from the list. I am wondering if there is a notable difference between these two implementations:

```
def withoutWord(w: String): Foo = copy(words = words.filterNot(_ == w))
```

```
def withoutWord(w: String): Foo = {
  if(words contains w) copy(words = words.filterNot(_ == w))
  else this
}
```

Is it better to check for modifications and return the current instance if nothing has changed or save this time and always copy? In my case, words should rarely exceeds 20 elements and the class has several other fields.

Comment: Both `filter` and `contains` are **O(N)** on `List`, thus checking before is just two times slower than just calling `filter` - You may consider using a `Set` instead of a `List`

Comment: Sorry for not being that clear, but in my case the order is important. Otherwise a Set was the way to go.

Comment: Other answers should give you a good hint but for such questions the best is often to actually run a benchmark test with "real data".

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "it depends".

Doing the `contains` check is a win only when it returns false, it is slower than just filtering when you end up filtering after `contains`.  So if you always call `withoutWord` with a word that's is already there, it's definitely slower and if you never do, it's definitely faster and there's a hit rate at which there's no overall difference.

If the redundant objects and collections are staying around for a while, that will be stressful on the GC (if they're short-lived, most GCs will handle it in such a way that the extra work is infinitesimal) and might lead to performance/stability issues down the road: in that situation, it may be warranted to pay the predictable cost of the `contains` check every time.

Answer (score 0):

```
    def withoutWord(w:String):Foo = {
       val selected = ListBuffer[String]()
       var isSame = true
       words.foreach(c => {
          if(c==w) { isSame = false }
          else selected += c
       })
       if(isSame) this else copy(selected.toList)
    }
```

This would be more effecient. However, its just a reference copy that we save.

Comment: Nice optimization! However this pay the cost of creating a modified instance of words, which is more expensive than checking for contains in my thoughts. Thanks

Comment: This is actually three times slower, the `copy` is meaningless compared to the cost of computing the `length`

Comment: you mean copying reference of filtered list to selected. Contains will have to iterate over list O(n). @Luis This is ArrayList length is known, what is computation here? Also, you mentioned three times slower, not the case for me.  This can be when LinkedList impl is passed instead of ArrayList

Comment: The `length` of a `List` is not know, it has to be computed **O(N)**. There is no `ArrayList` nor `LinkedList` just `List` _(which is N immutable linked list created as a simple ADT)_ - This is **Scala**, not **Java**.

Comment: Thanks @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez. My bad, got mixed with both.You are right!
From impl: 
Most other operations are `O(n)` on the number of elements in the list.
  *  This includes the index-based lookup of elements, `length`, `append` and `reverse`.

Comment: Since,  contains and filter both are O(n) and we are doing 2 times. We can club both and use ListBuffer which has append as Constant. Modified answer. Improves theoritically at least